# AC_SEARCH_LIBS when the function name varies

Tags: dll, makefile, autoconf

I have a program which makes use of `boost_regex`. The library `boost_regex` has an undefined symbol named differently with respect to the version of boost I am using. For instance, when I use boost version 1.49, `libboost_regex.so` contains an undefined symbol called `u_tolower_49`. This symbol can be found within `libicuuc.so`.

Obviously, if an user who doesn’t have icu compiles my program, the link stage will fail because that symbol is missing. So I decided to add it to configure.ac so that the configuration stage fails before starting the compilation.

**configure.ac**

```
...
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([u_tolower_49],[icuuc], , AC_MSG_ERROR([Unable to find icuuc, make sure ICU is installed.]))
...
```

Now my problem is that when the user’s version of boost is 48, the symbol is no longer named `u_tolower_49` but `u_tolower_48`.

How can I tweak configure.ac to make sure that the configuration fails regardless of the version of boost the user has?

Answer (score 1):

Nest the checks:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([u_tolower_49],[icuuc],[],[
    AC_SEARCH_LIBS([u_tolower_48],[icuuc],[],[
        AC_MSG_ERROR([Unable to find icuuc, make sure ICU is installed.])
    ])
])
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, but hm, there is also boost 50, boost 51, and so,on

Comment: @qdii That is an issue to take up with boost!  If they change symbol names to break the api, there is (probably) a reason for doing so.  You could ease the pain by using an `m4_foreach` loop, but any solution will be hackish.